# Paged.js: How can I set up an additional page counter for only a few pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagedjs

I need to display the pages of my document on the first few pages in roman numerals. From a specific page on I have to use decimals starting at 1 again.

For example the TOC, list of figures, preamble should have roman numerals. For all other pages I have to use decimals except for the glossary and all pages which come after the glossary. There I'd like to use roman numerals again.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS Page Media, you can count page with this, more detail >> https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#page-based-counters

```css
content: "Page." counter(page);
```

and set it again

```css
counter-increment: page 1;
```